# Repeating task at constant time intervals

Tags: linux, scheduled-tasks, task

I am looking for a crash-proof way of repeating a given task over a constant time interval say 1 hour or 5 hours. What I have found so far:

- ATrigger http://atrigger.com/
- Build a program that will make the calls.

I trying to avoid building a special program for this task because it's not crash and bug proof. I will also be wasting useful resources running the program.

**I am looking for something ready and widely used and well-developed.
ATrigger does not support repeating task from what I discover and I am not fan of the web calls since they are not so secure.**

Any other ways you might know of?

Comment: as Mike suggested: crontab -e, and make a line "* *,1 * * * x your fulll path command" ... http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html?hours%5B%5D=*&hours%5B%5D=1&cmd=x&pingsub=1

Comment: @Behe Anacron only supports 24 hour repeating tasks and according to their site http://anacron.sourceforge.net/ they do not guarantee the time of the execution.

Comment: You're right, I did not read the question correctly. I will delete my stupid comment to not lead some people to wrong ideas.

Comment: @venergiac Is cron starting by default at startup?

Comment: If cron is installed it will start by default at startup.

Comment: yes. sorry (I cannot edit my comment) "* */1 * * * command"

Comment: @venergiac: Sorry, `* */1 * * * command` doesn't make sense - it will execute every minute (I just verified). If you want it to execute every hour, you must choose a minute: `10 * * * * command` will execute `command` at 10-past-every-hour.

Comment: every hour means at 00 of every hour "0 * * * * command". Or every two hours: "0 */2 * * * command"

Comment: @venergiac: Yes exactly. So `* */1 * * * command` is misleading since it's equivalent to `* * * * * command`, ie every minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer can be found in the comments, but to be clear:

Install `cron`. Setup your crontab: `crontab -e`
Depending on your requirements, add a line for every task you need repeated.

```
# Execute this every hour at fifteen-minutes-past
15 * * * *   /path/to/command

# Execute this every fourth hour at zero-minutes
0 */4 * * *  /path/to/other-command
```

Answer (score 1):

I am among [ATrigger](http://atrigger.com/) team. Just to clarify, **ATrigger completely supports repeating tasks**. There is optional [count](http://atrigger.com/docs/wiki/8/rest-api-v10-parameter-count) parameter in all libraries and consequentially in REST API.

In advanced to the fact that ATrigger is a scheduling tool and security is not a concern in most cases, We have implemented standard security steps include Domain Verification, IP white-list and Request Verification to make sure all requests are valid.

```
ATrigger::doCreate("10minute", "http://www.example.com/myTask?something", $tags, $firstDate, $retries, $count, $postData);
```

Comment: Hey @Kousha need help with atrigger. Wanted to know the format of passing data in "postData" parameter of RestAPI. Thanks for the help. Docs don't help much in this case.

Comment: @AkshayR. As far as I remember, it receives form serialized information (string), and will be passed as same as the received data.